# (R) How do I row-bind data frames of a list in an efficient manner? Through a nested foreach or RCPP loop?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, rbind

Suppose `test` is a list of many data frames (with names). Then, the code

```
# Assigning key name to data frames repeated ticker names
for (i in 1:length(test)) {
  for (j in 1:length(test)) {
    if (names(test)[i] == names(test)[j] & i < j) {
      test[[j]] <- rbind(test[[i]], test[[j]])
      names(test)[i] <- "REPEATED"
    }
  }
}

# Subsetting data frames with non-repeated ticker names
test <- test[names(test) != "REPEATED"]
```

proceeds to row-bind the data frames of equal names and discard the non-binded data frames through the use of a nested `for` loop and a simple subset.

The problem is that it gets it done in a slow way due to the length of the `test` list, which contains thousands of data frames. Is there any way to rewrite this chunk of code to make it run faster? Does `foreach` or `Rcpp` nested loop construction present a viable solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `data,table::rbindlist()`.  It is fantastic, fast and memory efficient.  You will _not_ beat it with hand-written code.  (Also, we spell `Rcpp` as R c p p.  Uppercase R, lowercase cpp.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel We also spell `data.table` with a period :).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ok, but how do you use ```data.table::rbindlist()``` in order to row-bind only the data frames that fit on the (underlying) name pattern? 

For example, if the first data frame of the list has the name "TEST EB", such that ```names(test)[1]``` returns "TEST EB", and the second data frame of the list has the name "TEST EC", such that ```names(test)[2]``` returns "TEST EC", how can I benefit from the ```data.table::rbindlist()``` command to filter for the pattern ```TEST.*```?

Thank you anyway!

Comment: How about `l <- split(test, names(test)); test <- lapply(l[lengths(l) > 1L], data.table::rbindlist)`?

Comment: @Caliani21  One way is to run an `lappy` and inside the 'filtering' function check: if it matches, return it.  If not, return `NULL` as `NULL` gets omitted silient by `rbind` and `rbindlist`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Good point but see `fortunes::fortune("dirk can type")` from 2005 :)

Comment: @MikaelJagan It worked like a charm! I had to create ```test1 <- lapply(l[lengths(l) > 1L], data.table::rbindlist)```,  ```test2 <- lapply(l[lengths(l) == 1L], data.table::rbindlist)``` and then ```test <- append(test1, test2)``` in order to preserve the original, non-binded data frames as well. Thank you so much!